# How to connect link variable to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have a link code:

```
<?php foreach (range(0, 29) as $rs) { echo"<a href=\"open.php?&i=stone$rs;\"  id=\"link\">stone$rs</a><br/>"; } ?>
```

And here I have another code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_var = ""; //Here should be my "stone$rs"
    document.getElementById("link").onclick = function () {         
        // ajax start
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // all browsers 
        else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // for IE

        var url = 'details.php?js_var=' + js_var;
        xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
                var div = document.getElementById('update');
                div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
        // ajax stop
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

All I want to do, is to connect somehow my link $i value with js_var in javascript. Can you show me how its done?
Or can you show me how to do it with ajax and jquery?
And if you ca, show me how to open each link on modal dialog. Please.
Thanks.

Comment: where is the variable `$i`?

Comment: *"I can haz codez"* - surely that's a meme?

Comment: at my link.. see first code

Comment: you are creating 30 <a> tags with the same id.

Comment: thats true.. all i want to do is open each tag with unique $i id via javascript :) I am newbie at javascript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable in a data attribute:

```
<?php 
    foreach (range(0, 29) as $rs) { 
       echo"<a href='open.php?&i=stone$rs;' class='link' data-rs='stone$rs'>stone$rs</a><br/>";
    } 
?>
```

then in js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("link"),
      linksLength = links.length,
      i;
  for (i = 0; i < linksLength; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function () {
        var js_var = this.getAttribute('data-rs');
        // ajax start
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // all browsers 
        else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // for IE

        var url = 'details.php?js_var=' + js_var;
        xhr.open('GET', url, false);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
                var div = document.getElementById('update');
                div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
        // ajax stop
        return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: that really worked! thanks buddy! but i have faced with another problem. I have a 30 <a> links and when i press on first, its working, but another links isnt...

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id. Trying using a classname and binding your onclick handler to that.

Comment: You have the same id in each <a> tag, that's why only first one works. Use class instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsvar = <?php echo json_encode($i); ?>;
```

or try Jquery and AJAX

Comment: thank you, but can you show me how to do it with jq and ajax?

Comment: yes, here's an example i just wrote for someone else.
#1 get jquery http://jquery.com/download/ its just JS library that gives you a lot of extra and awesome tools.

here's a JS script

<script>
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async:true,
            url: "thephpscript.php",
            data: {MyPostVar:"data"},
            success: function(link_XML){
                 //the code that fetches the XML page 
            }});
</script>

Comment: heres the php in a seperate file called 'thephpscript.php

<?php
if($_POST && isset($_POST['MyPostVar'])) {
  $response = "/";
  if( $_POST['MyPostVar'] == "data" )
        $response = "You got data!!";
  
  echo json_encode($response);
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of it as "linking the variable" or in any way as JavaScript and PHP interacting.  JavaScript and PHP are entirely separate, one server-side and one client-side.  The server-side code (PHP) renders the client-side document, which contains JavaScript.

Given that separation, emitting values to JavaScript code is no different than emitting them to HTML.  The same pattern holds:

```
some client-side stuff
<?php echo some server-side stuff ?>
more client-side stuff
```

And the result ends up being:

```
some client-side stuff
the result of some server-side stuff
more client-side stuff
```

It doesn't matter what that "stuff" is.  It's all strings when it builds the HTML document.  So let's say you emit a value to HTML:

```
<div>
<?php echo $variable; ?>
</div>
```

The same works with JavaScript:

```
var something = someFunction();
<?php echo $variable; ?>
something.doSomething();
```

The server-side stuff is just injecting text into the resulting client-side stuff.  The interaction is whatever you want it to be.  Such as:

```
<script>
var someVariable = <?php echo $aNumber; ?>;
</script>
```

This may result in something like:

```
<script>
var someVariable = 5;
</script>
```

Or maybe you have a string to echo, in which case the client-side code would need quotes to know it's a string:

```
<script>
var someVariable = "<?php echo $aString; ?>";
</script>
```

This may result in something like:

```
<script>
var someVariable = "Hello world";
</script>
```

Essentially, the PHP code is just injecting text characters into the output.  Think of how you want the output to look, and inject the text characters where appropriate.

Comment: thanks for this info. appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a different way to actually select the element/elements that you are trying to get the text from. Right now you have a bunch of anchors that have no class or id. You cannot use document.getElementById to select an element that doesn't have an id. Like in your code above. You would need to adjust your php to echo something like:

```
echo"<a class="link" href=\"open.php?&i=stone$rs;\">stone$rs</a>";
```

Then if you are using a library like jQuery you can select your nodes via:

```
$('.link').on('click', function(){ 
    var linkValue = $(this).text();
    //your ajax here 
});
```

or:

```
echo"<a href=\"open.php?&i=stone$rs;\">stone$rs</a>";

//as long as you only have these anchors on the page
//but I would suggest a more specific selection like above

$('a').on('click', function(){ 
    var linkValue = $(this).text();
    //your ajax here 
});
```